# Como percorrer uma arvore hierárquica para gerar um HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**Estou com problemas para gerar uma função responsável por percorrer e retornar uma árvore hierárquica.**

Segue código JavaSript/JSON:

---

```
let tree = {
    label: 'Elemento A',
    itens: [
        {
            label: 'Elemento A1',
            itens: [
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A1a',
                    itens: [
                        {
                            label: 'Elemento A1a1'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Elemento A1a2'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A1b'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Elemento A2',
            itens: [
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A2a'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A2b'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Preciso de uma função recursiva para percorrer este Array -.-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com essa solução você pode percorrer e gerar o HTML desejado.

```
let tree = {
        label: 'Elemento A',
        itens: [
            {
                label: 'Elemento A1',
                itens: [
                    {
                        label: 'Elemento A1a',
                        itens: [
                            {
                                label: 'Elemento A1a1'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'Elemento A1a2'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Elemento A1b'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Elemento A2',
                itens: [
                    {
                        label: 'Elemento A2a'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Elemento A2b'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }


    let html = '<ul class="main-level">';

    (function printTree(tree, index) {
        html += `<li><span class="tree-label">${tree.label}</span>`;

        if(tree.itens) {
            html += `<ul class="sub-level-${index}">`;
            tree.itens.forEach((subtree, index) => printTree(subtree, index + 1));
            html += '</ul>';
        }

        html += '</li>';
    })(tree, 0);

    html += '</ul>';

    console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes percorrer assim

```js
let tree = {
    label: 'Elemento A',
    itens: [
        {
            label: 'Elemento A1',
            itens: [
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A1a',
                    itens: [
                        {
                            label: 'Elemento A1a1'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Elemento A1a2'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A1b'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Elemento A2',
            itens: [
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A2a'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Elemento A2b'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function mostrarConteudo(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
    var prop = obj[chave];
    if (typeof prop === 'object') mostrarConteudo(prop, chave);
    else console.log('<label>' + prop + '</label>');
  });
}

mostrarConteudo(tree);
```

Créditos da função [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)